# How to ignore a custom warning in clang?

Tags: objective-c, clang

I can ignore predefined Clang warnings as follows:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
        [target performSelector:selector];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

But what if there's a custom warning? I mean

```
#warning Hello World
```

How do I ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`-W#warnings` diagnostic](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#w-warnings), which I guess would do it.

Something like:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-W#warnings"
```